# How to resize a div with Jquery UI after changing its contents?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI to allow the user to resize a div with a video player in it. 
This is a excerpt of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $("#stream").resizable({
  containment: "#content",
  minHeight: $('#content').height(),
  maxWidth: ($('#content').width() / 1.3)
  });

});
</script>

<div id="stream">
<!-- Flash video player stuff -->
</div>
```

This works as expected when the page is rendered. The problem is when I trigger an event that changes the contents of the "#stream" div with:

```
#('#stream').html(<--!Code for another video player-->);
```

After doing this the resize controls disappear and even if I invoke `$("#stream").resize()` again is does not seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to use some sort of work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The widget will still operate under the parameters you specified on creation, even if `#content` itself changes. You can either completely `destroy` the widget and recreate it:

```
$("#stream").resizable("destroy").resizable({
    containment: "#content",
    minHeight: $("#content").height(),
    maxWidth: $("#content").width() / 1.3
});
```

Or, less intrusively, use the `option` method to update its operating parameters:

```
$("#stream").resizable("option", {
    minHeight: $("#content").height(),
    maxWidth: $("#content").width() / 1.3
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional element in `#stream` eg

```
<div id="stream"><div class="cnt"></div></div>
```

and update content by calling

```
$('#stream div.cnt').html(<--!Code for another video player-->);
```